# jQuery get text node siblings at deepest level

Tags: jquery, text, children, paragraph

I have `div`s that may consist of text like this:

```
<div>
<p>
<span>My text <br /> Some more text</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Or like this

```
<div>
<p> Here's a chunk of text </p>
</div>
```

Or any other combination, but the final level will have text that may or may not be separated by `<br />`. (Is a `span` that contains a `br` a single node? Or is it two siblings at the same level?)

In the first case, the text from the deepest children I want is:

```
My text
Some more text
```

In the second:

```
Here's a chunk of text
```

My point is - whatever the deepest level is, I want all siblings at that level. Any help?

### Edit

I cannot simply use `$('p').text()` because this will return the text only, which I need to edit and then return to the *same siblings*, while retaining their styles. So for example if I have

```
<div>
<p>
<strong>
<span style='font-family:arial'> Here's some <br /> text</span>
</strong>
</p>
</div>
```

And I do `$('p').text()` then I'll just get "Here's some text". Now when I manipulate this text in a variable, say `changedText` (with the `<br />` retained within it), how can I put it back where it came from? I can't simply do

`$('p').text(changedText);` and neither can I do `$('p').html(changedText');`

because the `<strong>` and `<span>` formatting will be lost. So that's why I just wanted to access all the text by selecting the deepest level of text nodes in a `div`, let's say in a `$textNodes`. So that I can simply do `$textNodes.text(changedText);` while retaining the structure and style of the parents of the text nodes.

Is that possible?

Comment: And why does `$('p').text();` not work for you?

Comment: I thought I can't use `$('p')` because I want only the text - and sometimes there's a `span` inside that `p`. And sometimes the `<span>` is nested in a `<strong>`. Also I do want to know where the <br /> is because I want to convert it to a newline for another format.

Comment: @user961627, I still see no reason for not using it. `.text()` goes through descendants

Comment: @Alexander I've edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: This plugin also may help you: https://github.com/martinille/jquery.deepest.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.children()` until you reach the deepest nodes. I wrapped it in a jQuery function as follows.

```
$.fn.deepest = function(){
  var $level = this.first();
  while (!!$level.children(":not(br)").length) {
    $level = $level.children();
  }
  return $level;
};
```

```
console.log($("div").deepest());
//[ <span>​My text <br>​ Some more text</span>​ ]
```

You can use `.contents()` to get the text nodes and manipulate them or `.text()`.

Comment: I tried the following: 

`mytext  = $('div').deepest().text();
$('div').deepest().text('');
$('div').deepest().append(editedText);`

But it replaced the original structure and formatting. I need to remove the original text and replace it all with the editedText.

Comment: @user961627, I'm afraid to say that the handling of the `<br>` is up to you. Since there's no unambiguous way to do it. There's no way to know where to put the `<br>` after you have edited the text. That's why you may use `.contents()` and try it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You could just target the `BR` as selector and replace it

```
$('p br').replaceWith('\n');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fhnHR/1/

If potential problem with other `BR` higher in the `DIV` use `.last()` to isolate last `BR`, or use `filter()` to check if the last one is in the deepest level.

Providing some more real world html examples that demonstrate potential depth and possible  tree structure would help. You could place them in fiddle demo and update it

Answer (score 0):

do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hWkkJ/2/

jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('.append').append($('p').html()); 
});
```

html:

```
<div>
<p>
<span>My text <br /> Some more text</span>
</p>
</div>

<div class="append"></div>
```

Comment: what does moving html to another element do to change the `BR` tag?