# Convert HTML-encoded &lt; br/ &gt; to html new line tag in jquery .text()

Tags: jquery, html, newline

I have some text in a variable `sometext` which I want to assign to `div` using `$('div').text(sometext);`. The problem is that all `<br/>`s in `sometext` turn into `&lt; br/ &gt;`. I cannot use `$('div').html()` because there's a lot of internal structure that I want to retain within the `div`, so I can only use the `.text()` function.

So once I've passed the text over the to the `div`, is there any way to change the encoded `<br/>` tag into a real line break in HTML? I mean something like this:

```
$('div').convertMyBRsToHTML();
```

Comment: you just asked this same question an hour ago, and gave no feedback on answers  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425152/jquery-get-text-node-siblings-at-deepest-level

Comment: this is not the same question - I am trying different approaches to solve the same problem, but both approaches are doing different things. although yes they seem related. I did give feedback to the previous question - however I did not choose an answer because although I tried them and tweaked them they did not solve my problem. The earlier question tried to get the deepest level of text nodes, here I am only replacing HTML-encoded <br> tags.

Comment: you need to provide some more real world html that can be put into jsfiddle.net , will save considerable time. Create several sceanrios within different main `DIV`'s

Comment: also... can't keep inner html structure of a `DIV` and replace it's contents with `text()` will not generate html because there is no valid html being passed in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requested function should look like this:

```
$.fn.convertMyBRsToHTML = function(text){
    this.text(text);
    this.html(this.html().replace(/&lt;br\s*\/&gt;/g,'<br/>'));
    return this;
}
```

Now you could use by:

```
$(YOUR_SELECTOR).convertMyBRsToHTML("<b>Some</b> new text.<br />next line<br />and so on");
```

Comment: well that's exactly what I was looking for! unfortunately it doesn't work for me. did you test it?

Comment: thanks! still not working with me, I'll try some tweaks for my code and hopefully figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `<br>`s before setting the text:

```
$('div').text(sometext.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi, '\n');
```